# compile error in git: imap-send.o: In function `verify_hostname'

Tags: git, gcc, compiler-errors, openssl

In preparation for upgrading gitlab-ee, I want to upgrade git to the latest version 2.37.0,
Error when compiling source code:

```
    LINK git-imap-send
imap-send.o: In function `verify_hostname':
/opt/tmp/git-2.37.0/imap-send.c:242: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
/opt/tmp/git-2.37.0/imap-send.c:244: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
/opt/tmp/git-2.37.0/imap-send.c:250: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
/opt/tmp/git-2.37.0/imap-send.c:250: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
imap-send.o: In function `ssl_socket_connect':
/opt/tmp/git-2.37.0/imap-send.c:277: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/opt/tmp/git-2.37.0/imap-send.c:278: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/opt/tmp/git-2.37.0/imap-send.c:280: undefined reference to `TLS_method'
/opt/tmp/git-2.37.0/imap-send.c:335: undefined reference to `SSL_get1_peer_certificate'
/opt/tmp/git-2.37.0/imap-send.c:293: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [git-imap-send] Error 1
```

I upgraded openssl to 3.0.3 some time ago

```bash
# openssl version 
OpenSSL 3.0.3 3 May 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.3 3 May 2022)
```

and the installation directory is '/usr/local/bin/openssl', add the dynamic library to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl3.conf

What should I do to get git to compile correctly？

Answer (score 2):

Well, after I set

```bash
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib64/
```

the compilation was successful.

The full compile command is:

```bash
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib64/
./configure
make 
make install
```

Normally using `--with-openssl` should work, but according to the comments on the `--with-openssl` option in configure, it looks in the /foo/bar/include and /foo/bar/**lib** directories.
According to the explanation of the [`--libdir`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL.md#libdir) option in the INSTALL.md of openssl, By default this is **lib**.`Some build targets have a multilib postfix set in the build configuration.`I guessed and confirmed that when compiling openssl, the value of the --libdir option has been changed to **lib64**, so Cause the lib library is not read when using --with-openssl

---

I may have found a more canonical way:

The full compile command is:

```bash
./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/ --with-lib=lib64
make
make install
```

By using the compile parameter '--with-lib' to set the lib directory name, I successfully specified the lib directory location of openssl.

#### I recommend using this method more

Comment: Note that the autoconf configuration for Git has `OPENSSSLDIR` for this: your method works, but isn't the recommended method.

Comment: Did you mean the '--with-openssl' option? I added '--with-openssl=/usr/local/' but it didn't take effect

Comment: I do, but I'm not sure what the right spelling is here (I think you'd have to literally mention the `lib64` part, I don't happen to have an ubuntu build to test on right now).

Comment: According to the comments on the --with-openssl option in configure, it looks in the directories /foo/bar/include and /foo/bar/lib.When compiling openssl, it is not mandatory to specify --libdir=lib, and multilib postfix turns the directory into /foo/bar/lib64

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've been following the NOTES.UNIX in the git sources, and didn't do configure.. following this answer and configuring before make did the trick for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked.

What did work was after installing the custom version of OpenSSL (by custom I mean not installed with APT) was to run the command

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib64
```

Now if you have installed OpenSSL with a custom prefix (the default prefix is `/usr/local`) then you need to change the command to reflect that. Lets say you installed it with `--prefix=/opt`. Then my solution would be coded as

```
sudo ldconfig /opt/lib64
```

Hope this helps someone.